# Java - Socket.writeObject() is really slow

Tags: java, performance, sockets, multiplayer

Hello I wanted to tell you that I made multiplayer for my game and it works, but from 1 side of Europe to other, it takes 8 seconds. There is not much to send, it only sends a object that has float x, float y and String username.

In server I have 3 threads: Accept, Send, Receive. And client has Send and Receive.

Part of server's send:

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getOutputStream()));
int client_state = list_client_states.get(i);
oos.writeObject(client_state);
oos.flush();

oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getOutputStream()));
oos.writeObject(list_data);
oos.flush();
```

It is similar for Client and here is server's receive (also similar for player):

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
int receive_state = (Integer)ois.readObject();

ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
DataPackage dp = (DataPackage) ois.readObject();

list_data.set(i,dp);
```

Comment: Thats a long time. Did you do network diagnosis? Whats the ping time from the server to this far-away client. You might want to use more compact communication format like [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf) or [Kyro](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/).

Comment: Okay I will see, I didn't do any pinging thing and now I will see protobuf and Kyro

Answer (score 0):

For sending an object that consists of just a 2 floats and a String, is not going to make much difference how yo do the serialization / deserialization.  Certainly it won't directly cause an 8 second delay.  (The impact of the serialization format is likely to be a few milliseconds or less, unless you are using network links with a really low bit rate.)

I suspect that the real problem is either a networking issue, or (possibly) some kind of synchronization bug in code that you are not showing us.

Comment: Hmm, synchronization. I never thought about it actually so I don't know how should I do it. I just have a while(true) loop in a thread (daemon thread I think it is called) which loops through all CONNECTED players (so its not sending to players that arent connected) and similar goes to client.

Comment: PS: I don't know how I did my serialization (I'm still new to multiplayer) but I implemented it in my object class that I send and now I've read online that writeObject automatically serializes it. I guess, and I don't know is my flush() on a good place.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use the time stamp to debug where exactly code is taking too much time.

```
long time=new Date().getTime();
```

System.out.prrintln("Tme stamp"+ (time/1000));

By this you can debug either time consuming in serialization or making connection.